# Can not import big CSV to MySQL 5.6 even using --local-infile=1

Tags: mysql, csv, import, load, local

I have a CSV file with about 600MB size. I wanted to import it using SSH into MySQL 5.6, and as I read, I can use `LOAD` command in MySQL 5.7
Due to it, I used `--local-infile=1` when connecting to MySQL on my server like this:

```
mysql -u mydb -p --local-infile=1;
```

And after that, I ran my code like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\'
(col1,col2,col3);
```

But still I am getting this error whereas I read everywhere I can solve the problem using **--local-infile=1**

```
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version
```

Do you know what is the matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works if the Server allows this:

see: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html

> The LOCAL keyword affects expected location of the file and error
>   handling, as described later. LOCAL works only if your server and your
>   client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if mysqld
>   was started with --local-infile=0, LOCAL does not work. See Section
>   6.1.6, “Security Issues with LOAD DATA LOCAL”.

Comment: Thank you. I went to my.cnf and enabled it there too and then, I could run the SQL command.

Answer (score -1):

Change your Php settings execution time to unlimited and import using 
 //Process the score on csv
            $location = $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'];

```
        $file = fopen($location, "r");

        while (($csvfile = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $firstClm = $csvfile[0];
            $secondClm = $csvfile[1];
            $thirdClm = $csvfile[2];
            //Insert to database
        }
```

Comment: I want to do it using SSH as mentioned in question. This way, operation will be done much faster than using PHP.